# How to edit a downloaded cdf textbook example or prevent someone from editing my notebook?

Tags: notebooks, cdf-format, conversion, editing, cdfplayer

I have downloaded from https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/textbooks.html the textbook example and I have opened it. I am trying to make some edits but I cannot. I opened the option inspector and all the `Editable` options are on `True`. Can anybody tell me how to edit it or, oppositely, how to prevent someone from editing my notebook?

Comment: thanks, so with regard to preventing me and others to edit a notebook when it is believed to be in the final version a good way would be using Option Inspector and untick editable?

Comment: everything depends on your goals. Which CDF you what to edit and why? Do you want to use nice snippets for your own code?

Comment: I was more concerned on learning how to "block" a code and text so that it cannot be changed. I noticed that the options of the abovementioned downloaded cdf were on true (editable) so I was wondering if there was some other trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do:

```
nb = Import["path/to/BriggsCochraneCalculus.cdf"];
nb = NotebookPut@nb;
SetOptions[nb, Deployed -> False, Editable -> True]
```

You can now save it as .nb somewhere.

---

Why Options Inspector does not work? I must say I don't know but here's a guess.

One could expect that

```
nb = NotebookOpen @ "path/to/BriggsCochraneCalculus.cdf"

SetOptions[nb, Editable -> True, Deployed -> False, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

should make it possible to edit the notebook, those options itself are applied (can be confirmed with `Options`).

The only one thing that comes to my mind is **Notebook Signature**.

Each cdf contains a footer similar to:

> (* NotebookSignature 7KNa5d9r5bEV5L5WXOW32XP4 *)

The signature is used by the FrontEnd to check whether a CDF was edited outside mathematica.

Additionaly it stores information about what a given notebook is possible to do. That is, the FrontEnd will know whether this is an Enterprise Signed CDF ("Target" -> "PlayerPro"`) or just a simple standalone FreePlayer document.

This can affect things like cell evaluation so I'm assuming this notebook signature contains a flag for a FE that this NB is not editable.

I don't recall any way to do this but maybe there was available for authoring.

Again, that is a guess, maybe I missed something.

At the end, it is still just a text file which we can easily adapt but keep in mind that this may be against the terms and agreements.

Comment: This is great! thanks

Comment: could you comment why this is working? I opened the Option Inspector and both Deployed and Editable are already False and True in the original file

Comment: @AndreaG Ok, edited, I hoped for more too :) sorry.